# How to create sub domain name on Digital Ocean server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2

I have deploy Ruby on rails application on Digital Ocean Server with Apache2.

I am using concept of sub-domain like- our website name is for example - "abc.com " and any person come to our site and create his eCommerce store with name "xyzstore" then we provide him sub-domain as "xyzstore.abc.com"

please tell me how to create sub-domain on Digital Ocean.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts
but change example.com to xyzstore.abc.com (your sub-domain) and don't include the ServerAlias.

also add a CNAME on your domain's DNS record. use the following values:

name: *
hostname: @

wait for the change to propagate...

hope it helps.